# Convert installed system to PXE boot image

Tags: boot, 16.04, disk, pxe, disk-image

I've installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 onto a computer, customized it, and would like to take that installation (from a local 32GB mSATA drive; installed files use about 2.6GB) and convert it into an image that can be deployed via PXE boot over the network.  How would I capture this installation, shrink it to the smallest size possible, and convert it into an image that can be deployed to the TFTP server in our PXE boot system?

Note we already have PXE boot up and running to deploy things like installation images.  We don't want to install locally via PXE, but boot from a known-working image that has all of our software, settings, etc. already in place.  This is to support a deployment of hundreds of computers with "identical" hardware and we'd like to build the image once and have them all boot from it.  These computers will not have local storage of their own.  If we make changes to the "master" we can just replace the file on the TFTP server and reboot the computers to boot the new image, at least that is the idea.